# Android navigating to parent Fragment Activity from within Fragments

Tags: android

The main fragment activity in my application has the following function

```
private final void insertFragmentIntoView(final SherlockFragment fragment,
            String tag) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, fragment, tag);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

The `R.id.fragment_content` is a frame layout and i basically insert a new fragment into this frame. Now the frame that i insert has a button that should take me onto a new screen. What i want is that all navaigation in my application should take place in my FragmentActivity. How can i call my FragmentActivity from with a child fragment ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make a listener class in your fragment and your parent activity will implement that listener .
Now register listener in your fragment and call method in which you want to perform some action.
More you can see this link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Example how fragment and activity communicate.

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment{

class interface MyFragmentListener {
doSomeAction();
}


MyFragmentListener myListener;
onAttach(){
myListener=(MainActivity )getActivity();
}


onButtonClick(){
myListener.doSomeAction();
}


}

class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyFragment.MyFragmentListener 
{

doSomeAction(){

//TODO perform some action from your fragment to activity
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using listeners is the recommended way of communicating between Fragment and your activity.

See this Android [documentation section](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) for infromation. Long story short they just implement a listener interface by the Activity class and cast getActivity() result in a fragment to a listener.

From my personal experience this is very convenient because lets you to:

Easilly switch underlying activity (e.g. you host entire fragment in a wrapper activity for compatibility in pre-3.0 and host this fragment along with others in 11+)
Easilly control if the wrapper activity supports callbacks or not. Just check is it does implement the listener and do your app specific actions if it doesn't.

Comment: Listener is implemented using interface. Or was it just a comment to show off you know something? Have you bothered looking into provided url before downvoting? So ignorant

Comment: Yeah, keep showing off how "smart" you are instead of answering a question and helping someone. Never thought this kind of people existed on SO, this is not YouTube after all.

Comment: Well, judging by your last comment, it looks like I'm chatting to a litte immature kid trying to show off here. And when you have nothing to say nitpicking on words is the way to go. So not worth it. Well at least I know now what company's software I should avoid using.